# Including another Pug view fails

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have three Pug files in a Node.js/Express application which follows the following layout:

```
//layout.pug 
html
   head
      title= title
      link(rel="stylesheet", href="link")
      script(src="links")
      // many css and javascript imports
   body
     header 
        // header section
     block content 
     footer
        // footer section
     // more script imports 

//index.pug
extends layout
block content 
    //some content 
    include slider


//slide.pug
div(class="xxx")
   //slider contents
```

The `include` keyword actually works here and it renders the `slider.pug` but the problem I'm facing is that it does not render the `slider.pug` page as expected. The `slider` page is rendered in a way that it does not load required styles and javascript files so the result is a messed up html inside a nicely rendered one (`index.pug` in this case is the nicely rendered one).

I've tried adding the `extend layout` line to the `slider.pug` but it also failed.

What is the appropriate way to include a pug file that is meant to rely on the resources included in the `layout` page such as css and javascript inside another pug file?

Comment: From your description that should definitely work. As it's static templating the whole thing should be verifiable in the browser. If you inspect the slider in your browser of choice does the class appear?

Comment: @John: Thanks, your comment helped me solve the problem. It was actually due to bad markup (tab character) in the slider page.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help!

Comment: Your naming is also inconsistent: `include slider` & `slide.jade`